# Blender 2.8 and 2.81 completely closes out when trying to render

Tags: rendering

[image: This is what comes up on my CMD and I’m not sure how to fix it][image]

I don’t not if it’s my CPU or GPU but last week I rendered an animation out just fine. Pleas help!

Comment: Wow. My neck hurts!

Comment: ERROR: S:11011: error(#132) Syntax error: "," parse error

Comment: Seems like that's the issue. Have you modified/recompiled Blender's source code or implemented any scripts?